# Why is the correlation coefficient of these two list equal to 1?

Tags: python, numpy, correlation

I have two list `a` and `b` as follows:

```
a = [4,4,4,1.1]
b = [4,4,4,1.2]
```

It is clear that the last value in both the list is different, still why do I get the correlation co-eff (from numpy) to be equal to `1` in the below code:

```
print(corrcoef(a,b))
```

output:

```
[[1. 1.]
 [1. 1.]]
```

Comment: Because 1.0 is the correct, exact correlation coefficient for that data.  It is 1.0 for any `a` and `b` of the form `a = [c, c, c, d1]`, `b = [c, c, c, d2]` if both `d1 < c` and `d2 < c`.  (Likewise if both `d1 > c` and `d2 > c`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You assume just because the last value is different, the correlation coefficient should not be 1. This assumption however, can be flawed.

The important thing to realize is that correlation is calculated only after adjusting for the scales of each list/feature. With that in mind, you only have two unique pairs of datapoints. The correlation given only two datapoints can almost* always be constructed in such a way that it comes as 1 or -1. This is because the actual values don't matter, since they are scaled accordingly *before* comparison.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
a = [60, 30]
b = [1050, 490]
print(np.corrcoef(a,b)) #still gives 1.
```

Compare this to what you essentially passed:

```
import numpy as np
a = [4, 1.1]
b = [4, 1.2]
print(np.corrcoef(a,b)) #still gives 1.
```

Two datapoints don't contain enough information to show that the correlation can be a specific value that is not equal to 1 or -1.

To see why the correlation of 1 can make sense here, consider a 3rd point that i can add.

```
a = [6.9, 4, 1.1] #gaps of 2.9
b = [6.8, 4, 1.2] #gaps of 2.8
print(np.corrcoef(a,b)) #still gives 1.
```

Perhaps this makes it slightly clearer why the correlation can be 1, because the data points in the two lists are still *moving together* perfectly.

For getting a different correlation value with 3 points, we can compare to this.

```
a = [7, 4, 1.1]
b = [7, 4, 1.2]
print(np.corrcoef(a,b)) #gives 0.99994879
```

Now we have enough datapoints to show that the correlation is not perfectly 1.

---

*regarding the almost, exceptions would be cases where one feature does not change at all. such as `a = [0, 0]` with `b = [0, 1]`

Comment: Thanks for the perfect explanation. So, there should be at least 3 unique data points in each set to get a correlation coeff which makes sense. But if I have such data as in the my original post, what would be the best way to find the similarity between them?

Comment: Nice explanation. Guess I would have focused more in the fact that this is essentially computing the normalized covariance, and being the last value small compared to others, normalizing will imply that the effect of a decimal place difference is minimal, leading to a result that rounds up to `1`

Comment: @SuhailSheth in such a case, you'd have to "define" similarity on some criteria. An example could be sum or average of absolute differences between the pairs perhaps. However, your criteria would depend on the actual datapoints and on a case by case basis. Generally, you'd want to have more than 2 pairs of datapoints such that correlation can be used reliably, that is a safer option.